# Reassigning input field, simple calculator with JQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple calculator, yet I was wondering how I can reassign the input field. Right now I get the following error-message:

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: res.split is not a function",
```

Basically I would like to split the string when the equal button is pressed and just show the result in the input field. Just imagine that something like '12-3' is typed in.

```
$('.equal').on('click', () => {
    let res = ($('.inp').val(value))
    let spl = res.split('-')


    $('.inp').val(spl);
```

However, as I'm new to jquery and javascript, I don't really understand why I'm getting the error message above.

Thanks so much for reading or even helping a beginner out! For now, only the button '1', '2', '3', '-' and '=' work.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

let numb1 = '1';


let value="";


$('.1').on('click', () => {
    
    $('.inp').val(value += numb1)
})


let numb2 = '2';



$('.2').on('click', () => {
    
    $('.inp').val(value += numb2)
})

let numb3 = '3';



$('.3').on('click', () => {
    
    $('.inp').val(value += numb3)
})



let minus = '-';

$('.min').on('click', () => {
    
    $('.inp').val(value += minus)
})



$('.equal').on('click', () => {
    let res = ($('.inp').val(value))
    let spl = res.split('-')


    $('.inp').val(spl);

})




});
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    /*grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;*/
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /*rows come first and then columns*/
    margin: 10px;
    
}

.box {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box-gr {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: darkgray;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.inp {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Users/f/Downloads/Calc-project/style-calc.css'>
    <title>Chat-Messenger Window</title>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
  </head>

    <body>

    <input class="inp" type="text"/>
    <div class = "grid">



      
      
      <button class="box-gr">(</button>
      <button class="box-gr">)</button>
      <button class="box-gr">%</button>
      <button class="box-gr">CE</button>

      <button class="box 7">7</button>
      <button class="box 8">8</button>
      <button class="box 9">9</button>
      <button class="box-gr">/</button>
      <button class="box 4">4</button>
      <button class="box 5">5</button>
      <button class="box 6">6</button>
      <button class="box-gr">x</button>
      <button class="box 1">1</button>
      <button class="box 2">2</button>
      <button class="box 3">3</button>
      <button class="box-gr min">-</button>
      <button class="box 0">0</button>
      <button class="box">.</button>
      <button class="box equal">=</button>
      <button class="box-gr">+</button>

  
    </div>



   
    </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: [`$('.inp').val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) is using to set the value for input, you need to use [`$('.inp').val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

```
let res = ($('.inp').val(value))
```

When you use the `val` method with an argument, you are assigning that value to the target element. To get the value of the input, use `val` without any arguments.

```
let spl = res.split('-')
```

Finally, the split method returns an array, not a string. For example, when you split the string "12-3" as per your example, you'd get `["12", "3"]`.

Edit: Given that you don't take decimals into account, and that its hardcoded for subtraction, this should do:

```
$('.equal').on('click', () => {
    // Get string from input
    const inputValue = $('.inp').val();
    // Split the string into two numbers
    const numbers = inputValue.split('-');
    // Subtract both numbers
    const result = Number.parseInt(numbers[0]) - Number.parseInt(numbers[1]);
    // Replace the input content by the result
    $('.inp').val(result);
})
```

This assumes that `.inp` actually has the value (ie: the `"12-3"` you mentioned)

Comment: thanks for responding. I tried to implement your changes, but can't make it work unfortunately. For now; the output ['12' , '3']  would be just what I want as I would know how to proceed from there. Maybe you could show me, that would be awesome! If not, I understand, no worries.